# How to open up a new tab in a pop-up?

Tags: javascript, html, tabs, radio-button, popup

I don't know too much about programming but somehow I managed to make a pop-up window work. However, I need that from inside the new window (the pop-up one) a button on the pop-up will open a new tab. But I don't need the new tab open in the main browser, I want it open in the same pop-up.

Is this possible?

How can I do it?

I show both the pop-up code and the redirection code that is, at present, sending people to another tab in my web browser, but I need to do it in the same pop-up window that is already open. Here is the code in the pop-up:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click aquí para escuchar Radio Lineage.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction()
{
window.open("http://localhost:8000/player/index.html");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here the code of the new tab:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
.
.
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://hosted.musesradioplayer.com/mrp.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
MRP.insert({
'url':'localhost:8000/stream',
'lang':'es',
'codec':'mp3',
'volume':65,
'autoplay':true,
'buffering':5,
'title':'Radio LineageChile',
'welcome':'Bienvenido a...',
'bgcolor':'#FFFFFF',
'skin':'radiovoz',
'width':220,
'height':69
});
</script>
.
.
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't open a new ***tab***. You can only open a link in the current window or a new ***window***. How tabs are used depend on the browser and user preferences.

Comment: thanks a lot, already do that in fact

Answer (score 2):

To open new URL in the same popup window, from your code, I edited to below:

```
var win = window.open("http://localhost:8000/player/index.html", 'newwin', 'height=200px,width=200px');
```

after run this line, new popup window will be showed with height=200px, width=200px.
To open new URL in the same popup windown (win), use this line

win.location = "http://www.google.com"/

You can replace google URL by any URL you like.

Hope it helpful!
Good luck.
Johnny

Comment: so you are telling me i must add "win.location" thougheder with the big code you post?, where exactly?

Comment: i try to do with the "win location" stuff, but nothing happend, i also try to post the first code and effectibly make apparead a pop-up

But i already can open a pop-up, i'm now in the next step, i want to make it open in the same window than the pop-up, i believe u if you say to me than that answer is the one but..

How exactly?, because i don't get it to work

Please, develop a little more how to use the "win.location" because when i press the button to open the new tab in the pop-up, nothing happend.

Comment: I'm not sure this is what OP is looking for. This code gives you a way to click on a link in the original window and have it open in the same pop-up as a previous link. I think OP is trying to open a ***new tab*** in the ***same window*** as the link code.

Comment: This does not answer the question which is to open a new tab in the popup window

Answer (score 1):

Here the code, just a very small code, that will open the new page as a popup window.Code is working properly.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
<body>

 <p>Click the button to open an about:blank page in a new browser window that is 1200px wide and 600px tall.</p>

 <button onclick="openWin()">Open Window</button>

 <script>
 function openWin()
{
 var myWindow = window.open("","","width=1200,height=600");
}
</script>

  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: i'm not looking for that, thanks, i already open the pop-up, in fact the first code is in fact the code of the opened pop-up window.

Because i wanna open a new tab in the pop-up window, anyway thanks ;)

¡Keep up the Good Work!

Comment: Thanks @user57129 for appreciating my work, actually i am new here and i am trying to work much better.Actually i thought that you are trying to open page in popup window so thatswhy i wrote the code for this.

Comment: This is essentially the same functionality as in the question

Answer (score -1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        win = null;
        function openPopup(){
            win = window.open("http://www.google.com", 'newwin', 'height=200px,width=200px');
        }
        function openOtherUrl(){
            win.location = 'http://www.yahoo.com';
        }
    </script>
```

you can use this code, I change URl successfully with it.
Hope it will be helpful for you!

Comment: This just opens a page in the same popup window