# Open a new tab or window from a pop-up window

Tags: html

This question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21970475/how-to-open-up-a-new-tab-in-a-pop-up) but never answered correctly. I thought I'd ask it again and maybe by rephrasing the question we can get an answer.

I have a page where users can add data to a form. In one section, it gets complicated enough and is used rarely needed so that when needed, I force the user to click a link to open a pop-up window to add info to that form. This po-up window does not have tabs. On that pop-up window I include a link to a docu wiki article explaining how to fill out the form that the user can click if needed. I don't want the link to reuse the pop-up window because the user then won't have access to fill out the form and read the instructions at the same time. What I am trying to get it to do is open a new tab in the already open browser (not on the pop-up window). That way they can have the instructions in the background and the pop-up window with the entry form up on top of that.

Using

```
target="_blank">
```

just reuses the same pop-up window and if the user had entered any data, the data is now gone.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: can you post more html around the target declaration?

Comment: I *think* you'll have to use an `onclick` handler to open a new window.  I wouldn't be surprised if browsers don't allow popups to open popups, though.  Seems like the kind of thing that would be abused.

Comment: What browser(s) are you testing this on? I did a simple recreation on my local and from the popup window if I have a link with target=_blank it opens a tab on the original set of tabs not in the popup window. I tested using Chrome. Edit: just tested this on Firefox and got the same results.

Comment: I am using Chrome.